# Getting Ckeckboxes values in table with laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox, input

I'm using laravel 5.2 and I would like to get the values for a series of checkboxes included in table. Here is the code in the view setting up the checkboxes:

```
<form action="{{route('updateTasks')}}" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        @foreach($pageWithTask as $p)
            <tr>
                <td>
                   {{$p->name}}
                </td>
           </tr>
           @foreach($p->task as $t)
               @if($t->ended==0)
                    <tr class="danger">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{$t->name}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"  name="task[]" id="task"></td>
                    </tr>
               @else
                    <tr class="success">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{$t->name}}</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" class="disabled" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
               @endif
           @endforeach
       @endforeach
   </table>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  name="task[]" id="task"></td>
   <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save changes" class="btn btn-facebook">
</form>
```

when I Debug my results in controller its show me only " save changes " , the value of my submit button
thanks.

Comment: Can you Explain it in more detail?

Comment: I see that you have a checkbox without a `name` attribute.  Have you tried adding a `name` and has that helped?

Comment: There is a `<td>` after the `</table>`. That should probably inside.

Comment: when checkboxes are in a table, the Input::get() or the Requests Cannot detect them

Answer (score 0):

Use `readonly` Instead of disabled for checkboxes and add name attribute.

Readonly values are not editable but are posted in form.

Disabled fields are also not editable but aren't posted with form.

Comment: i dont need the disabled checkboxes , my problem is when checkboxes are in a table, the Input::get() or the Requests Cannot detect them

Comment: Then why you have disabled attribute set? Plus have you set name attributes?